# Java generics why can't I instantiate a genericized type

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I was writing something using generics and to my surprise I found that this doesn't work:

```
class foo<T>{

 T innerT = new T();

}
```

So can't I instantiate the genericized type? Aren't there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty damn annoying.

The work around I use is to force the client to pass the class in when constructing a new `foo<T>` - i.e.

```
public foo(Class<T> myClass)
```

Then you can use `myClass.newInstance()` instead.

Comment: can't be less arsed... thanks man didn't think about this :D

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why. You should understand why it does this before working round it.

Comment: And T can be abstract class or interface, in which case the solution is absolutely not useful.

Comment: Other answers have explained the reason for type erasure quite well. I am happy to share to the rep without basically copying what others have said.

Comment: Although after years I understand type erasure, still there is no need for that. In fact genericized instantiation will be done at compile time, so if T is an interface/abstract class/class without a no-argument constructor, the error can be resolved by the compiler. Type erasure is a runtime problem, not a compile time one.

Answer (score 14):

At the runtime JVM doesn't know what T is so it can't create new object of type T. [Types are erased during compilation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: +1. Type erasure and what Generics *really* means in Java is a must.

Comment: Furthermore, T may be an interface or an abstract class.

Comment: Or an enum, or just an ordinary concrete class with no accessible no-args constructor.

Answer (score 8):

I would always prefer a creational pattern (factory, prototype, ...).
Especially

> ```
> public foo(Class<T> myClass)
> ```
>
> Then you can use `myClass.newInstance()` instead.

is a bad solution, because T may have no empty constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to "wrap" the constructor in its own object, and then use that object to create the class you need.

If you dont know what class you are instancing, well then you dont know if it has a constructor, thus you cant call it.

```
static <T> void myFunction(Provider<T> provider){
    T t = provider.get();
}

interface Provider<T>{
    public T get();
}

public class MyClass{
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    myFunction(new Provider<MyClass>(){
        public MyClass get(){
            return new MyClass();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation in the way java implemented generics. To allow compatibility of code using generics with legacy code before generics where added to the language, generics were implemented using type erasure. This causes a lot of confusion to people who come from langauges such as C++ and expect generic's to work in the same way.

To read more on the implications of this here is a good [link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: In fact I'm a bloody C++ programmer and I always get involved in projects with this f...g Java language...

Answer (score 0):

#### Workaround

You can use the template type of a class if you subtype it. See my answer to another question - [Instantiating generics type in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434041/instantiating-generics-type-in-java/2840318#2840318).