# Java generics - getting the type

Tags: java, generics

> [Duplicate: Instantiating generics type in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434041/instantiating-generics-type-in-java)

Hi!
I'm a c# guy giving Java a try .. so how would I do the following in java.

in C#

```
public T create_an_instance_of<T>(){
  T instance = default (T);
 // here's usually some factory to create the implementation
   instance =  some_factory.build<T>();
 // or even..
   instance = some_factory.build(typeOf(T) );

 return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Java's generics are based on [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). That allows them to be downwards-compatible, but means that you cannot use the type parameter itself, because it does not exist at runtime.

The closest thing you can do is this:

```
public <T> T create_an_instance_of(Class<T> c){
    return c.newInstance(); // or use constructors via reflection
}
```

Comment: for the record, this won't compile because of Exceptions ;)

Comment: and for the record, the downvote isn't mine. Seems like all answers were downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Java because generics are non-reified. You can use what are called "type tokens", but it has limitations.

```
 static <T> T construct(Class<T> klazz) {
     try {
        return klazz.newInstance();
     } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        return null;
     } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
     }
 }

 System.out.println(construct(String.class).isEmpty()); // prints "true"
```

This uses [`Class<?>.newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) to construct an object using reflection, which doesn't always succeed (e.g. when there's no public nullary constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public static <T> T createInstance(Class<T> clazz)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException,
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    T ans = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct choice is to use an Abstract Factory. Just pass it in, and it will even be able to create instances of classes that don't have public no-arg constructors, or of an appropriate implementation class of an interface class.

Reflection is absolutely unnecessary and the wrong choice here.

Comment: If he wants to use it for every type in his system, an abstract factory would be an unnecessary overhead.