# Instantiate an object of a class where the class is given via generics

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

I have some code:

```
public class foo<K> {
    public void bar() {
        K cheese = new K();
        // stuff
    }
}
```

This does not compile and Intellij's linter tells me `Type parameter 'K' cannot be instantiated directly`.

How would I instance a new copy of `K`.

Comment: Why do you assume `K` has a no-argument constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this nicely due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The standard means of doing it is to pass the appropriate `Class` object, and use this to instantiate a new instance.

e.g. from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html):

```
public static <E> void append(List<E> list, Class<E> cls) throws Exception {
    E elem = cls.newInstance();   // OK
    list.add(elem);
}
```

Comment: I know it's just an example, but note that you could make `cls` a `Class<? extends E>` to demonstrate [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

Comment: Thanks, but you forgot to add a method invocation: List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
append(ls, String.class); Even in this case I still cannot compile it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2434182/2914140, for example. It requires one new parameter in constructor.