# java generate th list of objects from database

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have two classes:

```
public abstract class Entry {
    private static String LIST_QUERY     = "SELECT * FROM \"%s\"";
    .
    .
    .
    protected static <T extends Entity> List<T> all(Class<T> cls) {
/*Here I want to load whole database. For each row create own object. For example Article(class is below)*/
   }
}

class Article extends Entry {
   .
   .
   .
    public static List<Article> all() throws SQLException {
        return Entry.all(Article.class);
   }
}
```

Question is how inside Entry.all() method create Article objects or any object inherited from Entry?
My variants are wrong:

```
cls<T> instance_of_entity = new cls<T>();//wrong
cls instance_of_entity = new cls();//wrong
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434041/instantiating-generics-type-in-java

Comment: You can use cls.newInstance(). More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html. But this requires passing in the runtime class (in the cls variable). Because of type erasure you cannot instantiate with T alone.

Comment: But how to create object? Object instance = cls.newInstance();? or Object<T> instance = cls.newInstance(); or Entity instance = cls.newinstance();?