# Java array of object which has generic

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have the following structure:

```
public class SomeObject<T> {

    int key;
    T value;
    ...
}
```

And in another class:

```
public class TestSomeObject<T> {

    SomeObject<T>[] data;

    TestSomeObject() {
         this.data =  (SomeObject<T>[]) new Object[capacity];
    }
}
```

Of course, that line in the constructor utterly fails with the Exception:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [SomeObject;
```

Are there any workarounds for this? Or is there any way I could restructure it to make it work?

Comment: What do you wish this to do : `this.data =  (SomeObject<T>[]) new Object[capacity];`?

Comment: Using generics and casting... Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434041/instantiating-generics-type-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
TestSomeObject() {
     this.data =  new SomeObject[capacity];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant't cast an new Object() to SomeObject.

Maybe you want something like this?

```
public class TestSomeObject<T> {

  SomeObject<T>[] data;

  TestSomeObject() {
       this.data =  new SomeObject[] {new SomeObject<T>()};
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    new TestSomeObject<String>();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Object in "new Object[capacity];" is java.lang.Object, it's normal. 
You can't cast a new Object into anything.
You have to do:

```
this.data = new SomeObject<T>[capacity];
```