# Generic Erasure concept

Tags: java

Could you please help me to understand the generic concept here.

```
// Can't create an instance of T.
class Gen<T> {
  T ob;

  Gen() {
    ob = new T(); // Illegal!!!
  }

  public static void main() {

    Gen<Integer> genobj = new Gen<Integer>(); //Error
  }
}
```

When your Java code is compiled, all generic type
information is removed (erased). This means replacing type parameters with their bound
type, which is Object if no explicit bound is specified, and then applying the appropriate
casts (as determined by the type arguments) to maintain type compatibility with the types
specified by the type arguments. The compiler also enforces this type compatibility.

My question:-Why java complier is throwing error here ?
Bevause after complitaion .

Thanks

Comment: After compilation, the type `T` is erased, so program won't know what type you are trying to instantiate.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong.'T' is replaced with Java.lang.Object

Comment: Gen<Integer> genobj=new Gen<Integer>() after complilation it would be Gen<Java.lang.Object> genobj=new Gen<Java.Lang.Object>()

Comment: T is not replaced with type Object. T is replaced by whatever you program it to accept by providing a type when you call it Gen<Integer> gen = new Gen();. If you want to create a new "T" type then you must use T.newInstances(); [Instantiating generics type in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434041/instantiating-generics-type-in-java) What are you trying to do, your code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways that may work out here:

From a logical POV:
It's not even guaranteed that whatever template-parameter `T` you use has a default-constructor. Which obviously offers the problem of how to handle the absence of a default-constructor. Possible solutions would be to produce a runtime-error, compile-time error or disallow any `T` that doesn't provide a default-constructor. The latter would obviously break the template-definition, which allows **any** `T`. And the runtime-error would complicate things quite a bit and yield the same problem as mentioned above. Remains preventing this behavior in the first place and throwing a compile-time error.

From a internal view:
Let's assume we could use the provided code. Then how would it work? Due to erasure, `new T()` would produce an `Object`. But what if `T` is `Integer`? Well, we're screwed. An `Object` is not an `Integer`, so we'll get a plain class-cast exception.

So in summary: allowing the above to compile wouldn't work from a practical POV and in addition break the current definition of generics in java.