# Java Eruser Concept,How it works

Tags: java, generics

Please answer to my question.

```
class parent<T>
{
 T ob;
 public parent();
 ob=new T(); //Giving error for this statement ,Parameterized can not be created
 }
```

Comment: That's a really strange way to ask question. Perhaps you should refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java

Comment: My Question is that,Eraser works like, Java eraser removes all the parameter type'T' with their bounded type,(If no bounded type specfied) it will replace the 'T' with Object.  ob=new T(); (it will be ob=new Object();) why complier throws error.

Comment: You asked this same question two months ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591889/generic-erasure-concept) and accepted an answer. What don't you understand? If you didn't understand, why did you accept an answer?

Comment: T might be a value type or might not have a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate type parameters. You might want to read [Oracle - Restrictions on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html)

Comment: Is it exception to the oracle eraser concept ??

Comment: No, it's the rule.

Comment: @alakhya Yes it cannot be done because of type erasure.

Comment: Just curious to know the reason behind it

Comment: It's because the compiler does not have any knowledge about the type. Therefore it does not know if there is  a default constructor available or not.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet ..Compiler replace 'T' with "Object" ,Object has constructor.

Comment: @alakhya Thats true. But its at compile time. At runtime it actually does not know which type it is currently handling. It might be a class without a default constructor or an interface which has been represented by the type. So it does not know if it is possible to create a new instance of the unknown type.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet                                                                                  before compile code is  Ob=new T();

After compile code will be Ob=new Object();

at run it is present ? Please make me correct here if i am wrong

Comment: @alakhya It's correct that there is an Object. Assume you use your generic code with a class that does not have a default constructor. What would happen? Java tries casting the Object into your MyFancyObject. The result -> ClassCastException at runtime. So Java was designed (the compiler) to prevent such a runtime error and instead tell you, that this code won't even be accepted (because else there could be errors at runtime). It's a way of preventing unessessary  errors.