# Java Generics: Question about methods with generic return type (but no generic parameter)

Tags: java, generics, jakarta-ee

I often use java generics but somehow I still manage not to grasp some concepts.

I have a simple class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class KcDashboard{..}
public class KcGroupHsDashboard extends KcDashboard{..}
```

A little helper

```
public class ObjectWrapper<O extends Object>{
public ObjectWrapper(){}
public ObjectWrapper( O obj ){
    this.obj = obj;
}
private O obj;
public O unwrap() {
    return obj;
}
public void wrap(O obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}
}
```

My problematic code:

```
public <D extends KcDashboard> D getTransientDashboard(){
    ...
    ObjectWrapper<D> wrapp = new ObjectWrapper<>();
    wrapp.wrap( new KcGroupHsDashboard() ); // Gives: The method wrap(D) is not applicable for KcGroupHsDashboard
    return wrapp.unwrap();
    }
```

Passing `Class<D>` as parameter cannot be done as I could wrap and return different types within the `getTransientDashboard` method.

Erasing types from the method I would get:

```
public KcDashboard getTransientDashboard(){
        ...
        ObjectWrapper<KcDashboard> wrapp = new ObjectWrapper<>();
        wrapp.wrap( new KcGroupHsDashboard() );
        return wrapp.unwrap();
        }
```

which compiles correctly.

I know I am missing something, but what?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po

Comment: I think that the problem's not related to the ObjectWrapper, as I cannot: return new KcGroupHsDashboard neither D dash = new KcGroupHsDashboard(). I think the problem is related to generics instantiation in some way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434041/instantiating-generics-type-in-java

Comment: Please also take a look at [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html).

Comment: The problem is that  <D extends KcDashboard> is not applicable for  <KcGroupHsDashboard> even tho KcGroupHsDashboard inherits from KcDashboard. Polymorphism don't work for generics like you expect it to. To List<Animal> you can add any animal but List<Animal> cannot be assigned to  List<Spider> same goes for your code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was deceived by the fact that in my example I thought I would never be able to specify a type for D other than its upper bound (KcDashboard), but I was wrong as, like Oleksanrd said below, I could call it as <KcGroupHsDashboard>getTransientDashboard();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look into a slightly modified example in order to understand the problem better:

```
public <T extends Number> T getTransientDashboard() {
    ObjectWrapper<T> wrapp = new ObjectWrapper<>();
    wrapp.wrap(Integer.valueOf("0")); // Error: Integer cannot be converted to T
    return wrapp.unwrap();
}
```

where `T` could be a `Number` or one of its sub-classes (Double, for example):

```
ref.<Double>getTransientDashboard();
```

as a result, you can not wrap an `Integer` when you have the `ObjectWrapper<Double>`:

```
ObjectWrapper<T> wrapp = new ObjectWrapper<>(); // T is Double
wrapp.wrap(Integer.valueOf("0")); // Error ...
```

And that's why the `incompatible types` error occurs - type safety comes first. The same applies to your initial example.