# Can I refer to subclass like parameter?

Tags: java, subclass, abstract

I would like to refer in my abstract class to any potential subclass like to parameter, to make universal functions, that would for example make new instances of subclass without overloading.

```java
abstract class Fictional
{
  public static ArrayList<SUBCLASS_PARAM> subclassArray = new ArrayList<SUBCLASS_PARAM>();
  int i;

  private Fictional(int i) //All subclasses have to implement this constructor
  {
     this.i = i;
     //body
  }

  public static SUBCLASS_PARAM loadFromFile() //I wouldn't have to override this method
  {
     SUBCLASS_PARAM subclass = new SUBCLASS_PARAM(1); //it's not possible to make new instance of abstract class, but it would be possible with any other subclass
     subclassList.put(subclass);
     return subclass;
  }
}

class Real extends Fictional
{
//nothing here
}

class main
{
  Real r = Real.loadFromFile()
}
```

Is there any way to make something like this ?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with generics.

Comment: What is SUBCLASS_PARAM?  Your classes are named "Real, Fictional and main"

Comment: @BillK Most likely it is intended to be a generic parameter

Comment: Considering loadFromFile not being static and with generic return type <T extends Fictional>, it would still not be possible to access Class instance and instantialize Real.

Comment: It is not necessary at all use reflection to solve this problem..

Comment: Take a look at this thread (and this answer in particular) https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434094/1356924

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I can do this type of stuff with generics. Thanks for answer ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with generics and subclases like this:

```
public abstract class Fictional<A extends Fictional> {
    public ArrayList<A> subclassArray = new ArrayList<A>();
    int i;

    public Fictional(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public A loadFromFile() //I wouldn't have to override this method
    {
        A subclass = this.build(1); //it's not possible to make new instance of abstract class, but it would be possible with any other subclass
        subclassList.put(subclass);
        return subclass;
    }

    protected abstract A build(int i);
}

class Real extends Fictional
{
    public Real(int i) {
        super(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected Fictional build(int i) {
        return new Real(i);
    }
}
```