# Method that returns the maximum of a 2D-Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, comparable

```java
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E getMaxElement(E[][] list){
    E theMaximumElement = new E();
    for (int i = 0; i <list.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <list[i].length ; j++) {

            if(theMaximumElement.compareTo(list[i][j]))
                theMaximumElement = list[i][j];
        }
    }
    return theMaximumElement;
}
```

How can ı write this code well? Is it true?

I want to find the maximum element. I am not good at Generics in java.

Comment: You can't create instances of generic types (that also wouldn't make sense in this context). Use the first element of `list` instead (`list[0][0]`). Also add a `> 0` to your if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my version:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E getMaxElement(E[][] list) {
    if (list.length <= 0)
        return null;

    E theMaximumElement = list[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++)
            if (list[i][j].compareTo(theMaximumElement) > 0)
                theMaximumElement = list[i][j];

    return theMaximumElement;
}
```

Comment: is it True? You have used for iteratorr such as me but nicolas haven't.

Comment: @YusufT. I used an enhanced loop, not a "for iterator". And as long as you are a new member, if one of our answers resolved your issue, we'd be happy to suggest you upvote (the way saying "thanks, it helped me", this action is optional) and marking one of the answers as accepted to mark this question as resolved so others will know.

Comment: Nikolas - Great way of conveying the message! While the answer by @Schred is easy for the beginners to understand, your answer has options which all Java programmers should know as they mature. Schred is a great learner and has above all, he is a person with a big heart. Thumbs up to both the answer!

Comment: Cannot agree more.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in your code:

- The [`Comparable::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method doesn't return `boolean` but `int`. Here is the description of the method:

  > Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
  >   In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.
- You cannot instantiate the generic object such as `new E()`. Check [Instantiating generics type in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434041/instantiating-generics-type-in-java).

This is a way to go:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E getMaxElement(E[][] list) {

    E theMaximumElement = list[0][0];                // initial value (the first one)
    for (final E[] array : list) {
        for (final E e : array) {
            if (theMaximumElement.compareTo(e) < 0)  // comparison is against 0
                theMaximumElement = e;               // setting the new maximum value
        }
    }
    return theMaximumElement;                        // returning it
}
```

The only condition is that an element `list[0][0]` exists, i.e. the arrays are not empty. Otherwise, you should modify the solution to use `Optional<E>` since the maximum is not always found (empty arrays).

As of Java 8, there is a simple way to handle such use cases using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream):

```
Optional<E> optionalmaximum = Arrays.stream(list)                    // Stream<E[]>
                                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)         // Stream<E>
                                    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder()); // Optional<E>
```

Comment: You have the same mistake I had when testing (;D): if you compare based on `theMaximumElement` the returned value will actually be negative in case `e` is actually greater.

Comment: Huh, the signs always confuse me. Thanks :D

Comment: Thanks :) I understood